# Change the current draw of a circuit without a potentiometer

Tags: electricity, electric-current

I wanted to know how is it possible to alter the current that is being received, simply via a press of a button in a circuit. I am referring to this part of the video https://youtu.be/hFLopMOIjc8?t=893 where the person was able to reduce the current draw from the mains, to charge his Tesla car, from 12A to 8A. I can achieve this mechanically, using a potentiometer, but in this case the person used a software to do so. I wanted to know the circuit behind this.

Comment: Power transistors, pulse modulation, any number of circuits will do this...

Comment: Might this be a better question for [Electronics.SE]?

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply

It is a large family of circuits, i've spent years studying some of them. They use transistor to switch connection on and off, to efficiently convert voltage and current to required values.

It can convert voltages with much higher efficiency than a potentiometer. It sets up a voltage that battery accepts with a particular current. Battery has very steep volt-amper characteristic, small change in voltage means large change in current.

P.S. voltage or current control SMPS are not that different, you can measure either, and change delivered power accordingly. Usually you need to control both, so that voltage is not exceeded when connection is lost, and current is not exceeded if load has just connected.